# $\lim_{n \to \infty} \langle f_n, \varphi \rangle$ - Generalized function

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence, distribution-theory

**Question :** Let $f_n$ be the distribution $<f_n,\varphi>=n(\varphi(\frac{1}{n})-\varphi(\frac{-1}{n}))$. What distribution is $\lim_{n \to \infty} <f_n, \varphi>$ ?

**First try :** $\lim_{n \to \infty} n(\varphi(\frac{1}{n})-\varphi(\frac{-1}{n})) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\varphi(\frac{1}{n})-\varphi(\frac{-1}{n}))}{\frac{1}{n}}\stackrel{H.R}{=} \lim_{n \to \infty} \varphi'(\frac{1}{n})+\varphi'(\frac{-1}{n})$

**Second try :** $\lim_{n \to \infty} =n(\varphi(\frac{1}{n})-\varphi(\frac{-1}{n})) = \lim_{n \to \infty}  n \int_{\frac{-1}{n}}^{\frac{1}{n}} \varphi'(x) dx$

How could I find $\lim_{n \to \infty} <f_n, \varphi>$?

Comment: from the first try don't you simply get $2 \ \phi'(0)$ from smoothness of test functions. hence it should be $2\cdot \partial_{x} \delta(x)$

Comment: @u215 hahahaha, yes exactly! Thanks! I understand what you told me. It is related to the Dirac function

Comment: maybe there should be a minus sign in my above comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approaches are both correct, you just have to finish them.

**First try:** this is the easiest method:

$$\lim \limits _{n \to \infty} \frac{\varphi \left( \frac 1 n \right) - \varphi \left( - \frac 1 n \right)} {\frac 1 n} = \lim \limits _{n \to \infty} \frac{\varphi \left( \frac 1 n \right) - \varphi (0)} {\frac 1 n} + \lim \limits _{n \to \infty} \frac{\varphi \left( - \frac 1 n \right) - \varphi (0)} {- \frac 1 n} = \\
2 \varphi' (0) = \langle 2 \delta, \varphi' \rangle = \langle -2 \delta', \varphi \rangle .$$

**Second try:** this is more heavyweight since it involves the use of Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem which is a conceptually subtle result:

$$\lim \limits _{n \to \infty}  n \int \limits _{- \frac 1 n} ^{\frac 1 n} \varphi'(x) \ \Bbb dx = [\text{make } y = nx] = \lim \limits _{n \to \infty} \int \limits _{-1} ^1 \varphi' \left( \frac y n \right) \ \Bbb dy = \\
\int \limits _{-1} ^1 \lim \limits _{n \to \infty} \varphi' \left( \frac y n \right) \ \Bbb dy = \int \limits _{-1} ^1 \varphi' (0) \ \Bbb dy = 2 \varphi' (0) .$$

To conclude, $\lim \limits _{n \to \infty} f_n = -2 \delta'$.